# Rails 4 JS TypeError: $(...).previous is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am trying to make a link called remove under a text field to destroy and hide it using java-script but it doesnt work and i am getting this error in the console `TypeError: $(...).previous is not a function`

here is the rails code in

`app/views/surveys/_question_fields.html.erb`

```
<p class="fields">
  <%= f.label :content, "answer" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :content %><br />
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to_function "remove", "remove_fields(this)" %>
</p>
```

`app/assests/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require cocoon

function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).previous("input[type=hidden]").value = "1";
  $(link).up(".fields").hide();
}
```

Comment: it is `.prev()`... so `$(link).prev("input[type=hidden]")`

Comment: Look at the search results for "previous" in the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/?s=previous.

Comment: @ArunPJohny i guess it worked as now i get this error `TypeError: $(...).up is not a function` any idea ? thx in advanced :)

Comment: Same problem, `up` doesn't exist in jQuery. Have a look at the documentation and choose the correct method for what you want to do. That's what the documentation is there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like a mix of jQuery and PrototypeJS. (No great surprise, PrototypeJS was *huge* in the Ruby community for a long time...)

Here's the jQuery version:

```js
// 1
$(link).prevAll("input[type=hidden]").first().val("1");

// 2
$(link).closest(".fields").hide();
// Or: $(link).parents(".fields").first().hide();
// Or: $(link).parent().closest(".fields").first().hide();
```

1. PrototypeJS's `previous` searches through an element's previous siblings for a match. jQuery doesn't have a function that does exactly that (its [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev) function only looks at the immediately-previous sibling, it doesn't keep scanning), but you can combine [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) (which builds a list of all previous siblings, in order with the first being the one nearest the original element), and [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first), you get something that's effectively the same as PrototypeJS's `previous`.

   And then to set the value, you use the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) function, rather than assigning to the `value` property. PrototypeJS decorates actual DOM elements; jQuery, on the other hand, is based in set theory and *wraps* elements. So jQuery instances don't have the DOM properties, but they have functions to manipulate the DOM elements they contain.
2. On the second line, jQuery doesn't have `up` but does have [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), which does something similar (although it starts with the *current* element when checking the selector). If the current element might match, you'll want [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) combined with `first` again; alternately, use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to go up one level, then use `closest`.

Comment: Or, as alternative to `parents` and `first`: `parent` and `closest`.